# How to randomly Change the background whenever i open activity in android(xml)?

Tags: android, xml, background

I have an activity in my application and I want to change its background whenever i come back on this activity . How can I randomise the images in my drawable folder and make them the background images of my activity. Note: It is only a single activity.

I am trying to make a item in **string:-**

```
  <integer-array name="MyImage">
        <item >@drawable/story</item>
        <item >@drawable/story1</item>
        <item >@drawable/story2</item>
        <item >@drawable/story3</item>
        <item >@drawable/story4</item>
        <item >@drawable/story5</item>
        <item >@drawable/story6</item>
        <item >@drawable/story7</item>
        <item >@drawable/story8</item>
        <item >@drawable/story9</item>
        <item >@drawable/story10</item>
    </integer-array>
```

and in my **activity:-**

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray myImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.myImages);
```

but when i calling that array(R.array.myImages) from string its not displaying here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**LogCAT:-**

```
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.angry.AngryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at com.xxx.xxx.angry.AngryActivity.onCreate(AngryActivity.java:69)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
12-21 17:33:25.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30832):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: see my answer, just copy paste

Comment: if found helful you can accept/mark answer :)

Comment: yeah sure!! i will do..if its working fine for me.

Comment: check my edit that is alternative way for do this

Comment: in your question you define integer array but that is not correct, it should be <item >R.drawable.story</item> .....so on.

Comment: do  you got your ans!!?

Comment: i am not getting how to solve rootview error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Of all I define array in the Images Like this:-

```
private int[] mbgIds = new int[] {
        R.drawable.Image,R.drawable.Image1,R.drawable.Image2,R.drawable.Image3,
        R.drawable.Image4,R.drawable.Image5,R.drawable.Image6,R.drawable.Image7,
        R.drawable.Image8,R.drawable.Image9,R.drawable.Image10,
    };

 Random rgenerator = new Random();
```

after that i define the layoutId onCreate Like this:-

```
 LinearLayout rootView=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

and at last I call(array) random Image background like this (where i am not able to solve earlier) :-

```
 Integer u = mbgIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mbgIds.length)];
        Log.e(TAG,"IMAGE_GET"+u);
        rootView.setBackgroundResource(u);
```

Last but not least In XMl LinearLayout with ID:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.43"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
         >
```

Special Thank's to @hardik Who help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

in OnCreate() method paste this......

```
int array[]=getResources().getIntArray(R.array.MyImage);
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(11);
Drawable cur = getResources.getDrawable(array[index]); 
rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(cur);
```

EDIT TRY THIS

```
int array[]={R.drawable.story,R.drawable.story1....};
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int index = rnd.nextInt(11);
    Drawable cur = getResources.getDrawable(array[index]); 
    rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(cur);
```

Comment: I have problem in MyImage its not displaying there..but i already define in string..its not getting from there..is there other way to get.

Comment: i think you should post log cat

Comment: after edition it look like this:- int array[]={R.drawable.story,R.drawable.story1,R.drawable.story2,R.drawable.story3,
          R.drawable.story4,R.drawable.story5,R.drawable.story6,R.drawable.story7,
          R.drawable.story8,R.drawable.story9,R.drawable.story10};
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.nextInt(11);
        Resources getResources = null;
  Drawable cur = getResources.getDrawable(array[index]); 
        rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(cur);

Comment: your rootView is your Layout on you want to set image

Comment: it is layout that you define in your xml

Comment: Ohh!! i am not getting ..should i define Id in my Layout..and call it on the Activity..Please Guide me..

Comment: yes first you have to define id in xml layout and after get it in activity by eg.LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewByid(R.id.layoutid);

Comment: i added your code but still i am getting same error in logcat.

Comment: dont copy paste my code this is just example. it will not work because your layout type and id will differ.

Comment: yeah i know...i created Id in my layout after that i call on my OnCreate then i call this code on rootview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43667/discussion-between-hardik-and-chandan)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
@Override
onResume()
{
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(11);
Drawable cur = getResources.getDrawable(ar[index]); /*I assumed ar as array of drawable Ids*/
rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(cur);
}
```

Comment: i am not able to generate any Id for that..can u help me how can i gerate it.

Comment: Use this: Resources r = getResources();
int[] ar = r.getIntArray(R.array.MyImage);

Comment: i am trying to make array in the string as i show in my question but..its not displaying in actvity after R.array...its not displaying image here.